# Send and receive IPv6 link-local multicast UDP datagrams in Python?

Tags: python, udp, posix, ipv6, multicast

This following is a straightforward IPv4 UDP broadcast, followed by listening on all interfaces.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, True)
sock.bind(("", 1337))
sock.sendto("hello world", ("255.255.255.255", 1337))
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(0x100)
    print "received from {0}: {1!r}".format(addr, data)
```

I want to adjust this to send and receive both IPv4 and IPv6.

I've poked around and read as much as I can and believe the following is roughly the route I need to take:

1. Create an IPv6 socket.
2. Add the socket to a link or site local multicast group.
3. Send the UDP packets to the multicast address for the group in use.

Further info I have is that I may need to bind to several interfaces, and tell the socket using `setsockopt()` that it should also receive multicast packets. Lastly `getaddrinfo()` can be used across the board to gracefully "drop back" to IPv4 where IPv6 isn't available.

I have much of this implemented, but stumble primarily on the multicasting parts. A complete code example in Python, or vivid description of the constants and addresses needed are preferred.

Comment: [this example gets a multicast on FF02::158 (IoTivity UDP CoAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52579755/8625835)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link to [python mcast demo](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo/sockets/mcast.py), does both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: This didn't work for me. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631891/problem-with-python-multicast-demo-code

Comment: did not work for me either. Is there a more up to date dual stack multicast listener?

Comment: @enrm see my answer in case it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently asking a question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487891/get-multicast-dest-from-python-socket-recv) that involves getting the multicast address of a received message, but the source code answers your question!

To listen:

```
# Initialise socket for IPv6 datagrams
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

# Allows address to be reused
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Binds to all interfaces on the given port
sock.bind(('', 8080))

# Allow messages from this socket to loop back for development
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP, True)

# Construct message for joining multicast group
mreq = struct.pack("16s15s".encode('utf-8'), socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, "ff02::abcd:1"), (chr(0) * 16).encode('utf-8'))
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, mreq)

data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

and to send:

```
# Create ipv6 datagram socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Allow own messages to be sent back (for local testing)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP, True)
sock.sendto("hello world".encode('utf-8'), ("ff02::abcd:1", 8080))
```

This is for python3.6, with python 2.7 I don't think the encodes are necessary. Also in the struct.pack line, I've seen variations of "16s15s" such as "4s", but I don't know what it is and what I have worked for me!

Comment: I think `mreq` should be formatted with `struct.pack("16sI")` according to the docs I can find about `struct ipv6_mreq`, e.g. on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-4415/sockets-149/index.html