# Get Multicast Dest from Python Socket Recv

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp, multicast

For my project, I need some way to know which multicast group a packet was originally sent to when it's received by my client. I've considered maintaining a map of sockets to multicast groups and identifying them this way, but surely there's some way to get the address from the datagram?

To listen, I'm currently using:

```
# Initialise socket for IPv6 datagrams
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

# Allows address to be reused
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Binds to all interfaces on the given port
sock.bind(('', 8080))

# Allow messages from this socket to loop back for development
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP, True)

# Construct message for joining multicast group
mreq = struct.pack("16s15s".encode('utf-8'), socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, "ff02::abcd:1"), (chr(0) * 16).encode('utf-8'))
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, mreq)

data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

and to send:

```
# Create ipv6 datagram socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Allow own messages to be sent back (for local testing)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP, True)
sock.sendto("hello world".encode('utf-8'), ("ff02::abcd:1", 8080))
```

Which works, but the address when received is that of the sending machine. How can I see the multicast group it was sent to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only joined multicast group address "ff02::abcd:1". Therefore, any packet that is received on the socket must have been sent to that multicast address.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I understand that, I'm trying to solve the problem for one socket that joins multiple multicast groups though.